# Why is clearTimeout not clearing the timer?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The code below listens for the users internet connection going offline/online:

```
let timer;
window.onoffline = () => {
  console.log('offline!');
  console.log('clearing timeout');
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
};

window.ononline = () => {
  console.log('online!');
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timer reached');
  }, 3000);
};
```

The problem I have is if I go offline, then online but then back offline fairly quickly then the timeout is still executed and I get the "timer reached" log. All of the console logs are executed as expected so when I go back offline window.onoffline is being executed and the clearTimeout should be executed - but it is not.

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/xhoku19m/1

Comment: You don't really need the `if (timer)` tests; it's not an error to pass garbage to `clearTimeout()`. So what exactly is the sequence of log messages you see in the "bad" cases?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with FF, is there a specific browser or environment failing to clear the timer?

Comment: The output of your console.logs will likely provide an answer.  One possibility is that you are getting 2 "online!" before an "offline!".   In this case, the `timer=` is overwritten by the 2nd *online* before it has been cleared by the first *offline*, so the first timer is never cleared.   Use a `stack` for timer instead of a single variable.

Comment: ... or always do a `clearTimeout()` before setting up a new one.

Comment: As others have said, the issue is not clearing the timer it's spawning multiple timers at the same time!

Comment: none of those suggestions are correct. Try the fiddle - you don't see multiples "online!" logs

Comment: I don't see *any* logs in the fiddle...

Comment: you have to right click on the bottom right hand panel - which is the webpage where the code is running. I'm fairly certain the issue is that there are multiple timers running as you mentioned and I will need to use some sort of stack and refer to each timer by some unique id but I don't really fully get why it's happening

Comment: If you go offline, then online, then offline again you still get the "timer reached" log, even though the timer should have been cleared by the last offline event

Comment: Open fiddle, run, F12, network, select the throttling drop down, toggle between offline and any online as fast as possible many times - leaving it offline.  At no point does it show "timer reached".   Can't reproduce.   It's unclear how you're testing on/offline - "right click on bottom right panel [in the fiddle]"?   Perhaps there's a delay?  Perhaps it's your browser version?  Latest Chrome here.  Follow @Pointy's suggestion above and clearTimeout immediately *before* adding a new one.

Comment: yep it's the bottom right hand panel in jsfiddle - if you right click on that and go "inspect" you'll get the dv tools for that iframe. then you will see the logs. But don't worry I've solved this using redux saga now which is a library I'm using - I'm juts racing two actions and it works perfectly: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects/

Answer (score -1):

This is related to the behavior of `window.onoffline` and `window.ononline` events, they are not stable especially when the network connection state changes quickly.

One way to address this problem is by creating your own custom mechanism; to do so, you can use `navigator.onLine` instead. Something like this:

```js
let timer;
let isOnline = navigator.onLine;

const onOnline = () => {
  if (!isOnline) {
    console.log('online!');
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timer reached');
    }, 3000);
  }
  isOnline = true;
};

const onOffline = () => {
  if (isOnline) {
    console.log('offline!');
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
      console.log('clearing timeout');
    }
  }
  isOnline = false;
};

window.addEventListener('online', onOnline);
window.addEventListener('offline', onOffline);
```

When the connection status changes, the corresponding custom event handler is called.

Comment: What is the value of manually keeping track of `isOnline` instead of directly using `navigator.onLine`?

Comment: Also I very strongly suspect that the exact same internal mechanism is responsible for maintaining `navigator.onLine` and firing the events, so I would be extremely surprised if this helped in any way.

Comment: @VLAZ it does help avoid some race conditions that can happen under certain scenarios (if the project gets bigger), for example where the online status changes between the time you read `navigator.onLine` and perform an action based on it. If you only need to know whether the user is online or offline, using `navigator.onLine` directly can be good, but as I said, ONLY if it is a quick straightforward test, not in a bigger project.